# Need solution for automated testing of web application

Tags: web-applications, automated-tests, regression

There are testing solutions like selenium and webdriver for testing web applications. However those would be sort of overkill for me as I'm looking for a simple testing solution that sends the data using get/post and analyzes the received html code. So I'm definitely not looking something that requires browser integration etc. Got some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) works very well for this. It even understands complicated pages using jQuery.

Comment: I have been using it for years with great results.

Answer (score 0):

Try cron jobs automating a script to do that

Comment: I could but that defeats the whole point. I'm looking for a simple framework, rather than me making all the scripts.